# Laravel mix compile progress stuck (WSL)

Tags: laravel, webpack, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-mix

I'm not sure if there is an issue here but it's been bothering me for a while. Whenever I'm using Laravel mix the various progress bars never complete and there are big gaps in the output, everything else appears to function correctly but it's just starting to annoy me a little as I'm wondering if something isn't setup quite right, the progress bars always seem to stall at the same point. I've attached an image from vscode console, is this normal? I've also made a stripped back example to test.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0"
  }
}
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
    .setPublicPath('dist')
    .js('src/app.js', 'dist')
    .sass('src/app.scss', 'dist').options({
        processCssUrls: false,
    });
```

[image: Laravel Mix output]

Win 10 WSL
Node: 16.15.0
NPM: 8.5.5

Looking over some similar issues, this seems to be caused by symlinks. Does WSL use symlinks for anything?

Thanks!